# Summary statistics in visual basic

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, statistics

Below I am trying to write a script the goal of which is to calculate some summary statistics for a few different columns of numbers.  I have gotten some help on it up to the "Need help below" mark.  But beyond that I am flabergasted as to how to calculate the simple stats (sum, mean, standard deviation, coefficient of variation).  I know VB has scripts for these stats, which I have included in my code, but I guess I need to do some extra declaring or something.  Advice much appreciated.  Thanks.

```
    Sub TOAinput()

    Const n As Integer = 648

    Dim stratum(n), hybrid(n), acres(n), hhsz(n), offinc(n)
    Dim s1 As Integer
    Dim s2 As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To n
    stratum(i) = Worksheets("hhid level").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
    Next i

    s1 = 0
    s2 = 0
    For i = 1 To n
        If stratum(i) = 1 Then
        s1 = s1 + 1
        Else:
        s2 = s2 + 1
        End If
    Next i

    Dim acres1(), hhsz1(), offinc1(), acres2(), hhsz2(), offinc2()
    ReDim acres1(s1), hhsz1(s1), offinc1(s1), acres2(s2), hhsz2(s2), offinc2(s2)

    'data infiles: acres, hh size, off-farm income,

    For i = 1 To n
    acres(i) = Worksheets("hhid level").Cells(i + 1, 4).Value
    hhsz(i) = Worksheets("hhid level").Cells(i + 1, 5).Value
    offinc(i) = Worksheets("hhid level").Cells(i + 1, 6).Value
    Next i

    s1 = 0
    s2 = 0
    For i = 1 To n
        If stratum(i) = 1 Then
        s1 = s1 + 1
        acres1(s1) = acres(i)
        hhsz1(s1) = hhsz(i)
        offinc1(s1) = offinc(i)
        Else:
        s2 = s2 + 1
        acres2(s2) = acres(i)
        hhsz2(s2) = hhsz(i)
        offinc2(s2) = offinc(i)
        End If
    Next i

    '****************************
    'Need help below
    '****************************

    Dim sumac1, sumac2, mhhsz1, mhhsz2, cvhhsz1, cvhhsz2

    sumac1 = Sum(acres1)
    sumac2 = Sum(acres2)
    mhhsz1 = Average(hhsz1)
    mhhsz2 = Average(hhsz2)
    cvhhsz1 = StDev(hhsz1) / Average(hhsz1)
    cvhhsz2 = StDev(hhsz2) / Average(hhsz2)


    End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The code doesn't seem to have any errors in it, but it doesn't do anything -- it's a sub, so there's no result and you don't output your stats anywhere.

Comment: Are you asking for a source for the statistics functions or are you having a specific error. As an aside I would enable [Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) so that you are not doing any implicate type conversions.

Comment: @MarcThibault I'm trying to get the mean etc. of the variables at the end of the code.  For example, I want to sum up the "acres1" variable.  And then I would want to output that sum onto an excel worksheet (but I forgot to include code for that in this post).  The main point is that "sumac1=Sum(acres1)" is not doing the trick.  I get an error message.  If someone could just show me how to sum "acres1" or get the mean of "hhsz1" and output it onto a worksheet that would be great.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do anything like this in code? If you really want to walk the Excel road, use the Excel way: formulas in cells...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum, Average and StdDev are worksheet functions and cannot be used directly in VBA.

Try

```
 MyInteger = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MyIntegerArray)
```

if Nick Sabbe's suggestion that you place formulae in cells is inappropriate.